# xdvipdfmx pdf_ref_obj() error with fontawesome

Tags: xetex, fontawesome

The following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\begin{document}
Text Text \faMobilePhone\ Text Text
\end{document}
```

when compiled with:

- `pdflatex` and `lualatex`, works like a charm,
- `xelatex`, is subject to the error:

  > xdvipdfmx:fatal: pdf_ref_obj(): passed invalid object.

  (and cannot create any PDF file).

Do you know what's going on?

### Update

As requested by egreg, here is the console output of `xelatex -output-driver="xdvipdfmx -vv" test.tex`:

```
<FONTMAP:/home/bitouze/.texlive2016/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map><FONTMAP:/home/bitouze/.texlive2016/texmf-var/fonts/map/dvipdfmx/updmap/kanjix.map><FONTMAP:/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/map/dvipdfmx/ckx.map>No dvi filename specified, reading standard input.
stdin -> test.pdf
DVI Comment:  XeTeX output 2016.10.14:1020
<AGL:texglyphlist.txt><AGL:pdfglyphlist.txt><AGL:glyphlist.txt>[1</usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman10-regular.otf@9.96pt<NATIVE-FONTMAP:/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman10-regular.otf/0/H/65536/0/0>
fontmap: /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman10-regular.otf/0/H/65536/0/0 -> /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman10-regular.otf(Identity-H)

pdf_font>> Input encoding "Identity-H" requires at least 2 bytes.
pdf_font>> The -m <00> option will be assumed for "/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman10-regular.otf".
(CID:LMRoman10-Regular)
pdf_font>> Type0 font "/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman10-regular.otf" cmap_id=<Identity-H,0> opened at font_id=</usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman10-regular.otf/0/H/65536/0/0,0>.
></usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/fontawesome/FontAwesome.pfb@9.96pt<NATIVE-FONTMAP:/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/fontawesome/FontAwesome.pfb/0/H/65536/0/0>
fontmap: /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/fontawesome/FontAwesome.pfb/0/H/65536/0/0 -> /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/fontawesome/FontAwesome.pfb(Identity-H)

pdf_font>> Input encoding "Identity-H" requires at least 2 bytes.
pdf_font>> The -m <00> option will be assumed for "/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/fontawesome/FontAwesome.pfb".
(CID:FontAwesome)
pdf_font>> Type0 font "/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/fontawesome/FontAwesome.pfb" cmap_id=<Identity-H,0> opened at font_id=</usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/fontawesome/FontAwesome.pfb/0/H/65536/0/0,1>.
>]
otf_cmap>> Creating ToUnicode CMap for "/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman10-regular.otf"...
(CID:/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman10-regular.otf[VESFSG+LMRoman10-Regular][CIDFontType0][6 glyphs][1055 bytes])(CID:/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/fontawesome/FontAwesome.pfb[QZYGOD+FontAwesome][CIDFontType0]
xdvipdfmx:warning: Invalid CMap
xdvipdfmx:fatal: pdf_ref_obj(): passed invalid object.
```

If I'm right, it points out that `xetex` or `xdvipdfmx` find the wrong `type1` font (as guessed by Ulrike Fischer) but I'm still puzzled: what can I do against that? BTW:

```
$ fc-list | grep 'fontawesome'
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/fontawesome/FontAwesome.pfb: FontAwesome:style=Regular
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/fontawesome/FontAwesome.otf: FontAwesome:style=Regular
```

Comment: Works fine for me, and my first guess is always that xetex or xdvipdfmx find the wrong font (e.g. the type1 font).

Comment: I have no problem. Can you compile the example from the command line with `xelatex -output-driver="xdvipdfmx -vv" test.tex` and report the final part of the console output?

Comment: You could try `\newfontfamily{\FA}{FontAwesome.otf}` after loading the package.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I doesn't work either.

Comment: @DenisBitouzé I can try later on a Linux box.

Comment: Remove
`/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/type1`
in your fonts.conf or local.conf for fontconfig, because type1 fonts are almost unusable as native fonts.

Comment: Try to change Urlike's comment as
`\newfontfamily{\FA}{[FontAwesome.otf]}`

Comment: @AkiraKakuto Each of your suggestions does the trick! Please convert your comments into an answer in order I can accept it.

Comment: @egreg However, if you are using Emacs, do NOT remove Type1 from fontconfig, otherwise the minibuffer rubric will be garbled, because it uses some Type1 fonts by default (I don't know which).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try

```
\newfontfamily{\FA}{[FontAwesome.otf]}
```

after loading the fontawesome package
(a simple modification of the comment by Ulrike Fischer).
In general, directories for type1 fonts should be removed from
search paths for fontconfig. Type1 fonts are almost
unusable as native fonts in XeTeX,
except for very simple encoding.

Comment: Just in case another person gets the same issue. Changing `\newfontfamily` to `\setfontfamily` does the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is to *reject* type1 fonts.

Add this `<glob>`-line to `/etc/fonts/fonts.conf` like this (take care of the correct parent tags):

```
<fontconfig>
    <selectfont>
        <rejectfont>
            <glob>/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/*</glob>
        </rejectfont>
    </selectfont>
</fontconfig>
```

*Attention*: The commentar in the `fonts.conf` file says you should use `local.conf` instead of this file. But it is not on my system.