# Utopia font results in "Invalid font" mesage

Tags: fontspec

I have a document which I previously have typeset without problems. After an upgrade my Linux computer, I cannot use the Utopia font any longer.

This simple document no longer works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Utopia}
\begin{document}
Hello world.
\end{document}
```

I compile it using xelatex, which results in this error message:

```
xdvipdfmx:fatal: Invalid font: -1 (0)
```

Utopia is installed on my computer. The `fc-list` command produces output containing these lines:

```
/usr/share/fonts/type1/texlive-fonts-recommended/putb8a.pfb: Utopia:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/type1/texlive-fonts-recommended/putri8a.pfb: Utopia:style=Italic
/usr/share/fonts/type1/texlive-fonts-recommended/putr8a.pfb: Utopia:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/type1/texlive-fonts-recommended/putbi8a.pfb: Utopia:style=Bold Italic
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: they are type1 fonts that you want to hide from fontconfig (and so xetex) so that it finds the opentype versions.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle How do I hide them?

Comment: that depends on how you added them although since it's /usr/share perhaps it's your linux package manager that added them, which is unfortunate, but see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/396495/1090  for a local fontcontfig to omit type1 fonts.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you, David. If you turn your comment into an answer, I'll acknowledge it as the answer to my question.

Comment: glad that worked I marked it as a dup

Comment: You could use the Erewhon OpenType fonts which are Utopia clones.